# Syntax Error on Get function in requests module

Tags: python-3.x

My code throws up syntax error on trying to download data from NYSE site get request functions.

I have changed the format of url string yet the error reappeared.

```
def get_decade(start=1920, end=1929, extension='prn'):
    try:
        link = requests.get(f"https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/data/Daily_Share_Volume_{start}-{end}.{extension}")
        file = os.path.join("..","Data", f"Daily_Share_Volume_{start}-{end}.{extension}")
        if link.status_code ==404:
            raise
        else:
            with open(file, "w") as temp_file:
                temp_file.write(str(link.content.decode("utf-8")))
            print(f"Successfully downloaded {start}-{end}")
    except:
        print("There was an issue with the download. \n\
 You may need a different date range or file extension. \n\
 Check out https://www.nyse.com/data/transactions-statistics-data-library")
```

The error message upon calling the function.

```
 link = requests.get(f"https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/data/Daily_Share_Volume_{start}-{end}.{extension}")
                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Resolution that will clear the invalid syntax error.

Comment: it worked with python 3.7

Comment: @Joe, is throwing up syntax error from my end. My main focus is on successfully downloading the file and saves it link variable. I know how to retrieve the file. I 'm using Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

> As of **Python 3.6**, f-strings are a great new way to format strings.

You stated in a comment that

> I know how to retrieve the file. **I 'm using Python 3.5**

In other words, upgrade your Python version or don't use f-strings.